# How to get empty database dump in sql server 2000?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

Am using sql server 2000, i need database structure from existing database without data. so, how can i get empty database dump. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

A simple try is to use Generate Scripts under Tasks if you right click the database. This is somewhat limited. There are also commercial tools that generate scripts for an existing database. ( Have a look at http://www.apexsql.com/ or http://www.red-gate.com/ for example). Another way would be duplicate the database, empty the copy and make a backup. Don't forget to cut the transaction log.

Some ways, no long thought. The way I would go iwould be depending on complexity of the database as well as the size.

Answer (score 1):

One way that might be appropriate (depending on what you want of course) is to take the SQL Server Management Studio, right click on the database and do the generate scripts Wizard. It will make a script with all objects (selectable) that can be used to create an empty database.

Or you can clone the DB and truncate all tables...

Comment: thanks for response. actually i want to create new db from existing db data structure. i have already used clone DB and truncate method. my question is some another ways do?

Comment: One thing you also could try is to use the SMO (SQL Server Management Objects) which are included with SQL Server. There you can access creation statements that way - this is what the management studio uses itself, so you get about the same this - but you can automate it if needed. Let me know if you need any help with that...

Answer (score 0):

Use the `desc` command followed by the table name for individual tables to get structure with out data.